# Identify Ritchey SPD pedals

Tags: pedals-clipless

I’m trying to figure out the model of these Ritchey pedals from circa 1998. My ultimate goal is to figure out if the bearings can be replaced.

[image: Mystery Ritcheys]

Comment: Could you open the axle and take a look at the bearings?

Comment: @ChristianLindig I’ve removed the spindles, bearing are cartridge type, not loose

Comment: I would expect that the bearings can be found in a catalog for industrial mechanical supplies. Maybe post a picture and some measurements of them.

Comment: @ChristianLindig I was hoping to get some info on the pedals and find out if bearings are available *before* driving the bearings out, of even finding out if the bearings can be driven out.

Comment: It's probably not worth replacing considering the price of bearings and the price of new pedals. Sadly!